# conversion of int to custom struct c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am trying to create a new object of type `pointT` from a `Vector<int>` coords.  This is where my tutorial has led me, but I get the error that it cannot convert an int to a `object pointT`.  `setWall` expects `(a,b, bool)` where `a` and `b` are of type `pointT`.

If this is not the way, how do I build `xy` from my vector?

Thanks

```
pointT xy =
{
    coords[0],
    coords[1]
};

m.setWall(xy.col, xy.col, false);}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Rob, I see how to format it appropriately, now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
struct point_t {
    int x;
    int y;
    point_t(const Vector<int>& v)
        :x(v.x),
         y(v.y)
    {}
};

point_t a(vecA);
point_t b(vecB);

m.setWall(a, b, false);
```

Comment: Thanks erenon.  I can't try it out right now but I will as soon as I get back from lunch.